# How i can navigate in buffers in specific .py files

Tags: key-bindings

I use emacs 24.5.1 and i use this hotkeys for navigate in my buffers, but I need navigate only in *.py files.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") 'next-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-'") 'previous-buffer)
```

I just started learning Lisp, I have no idea how I can do this. Thanks for any help.

UPD:
I want same as *next-buffer* but only in *.py files. For example, I have this buffers: *file.txt, file.el, file.py* and *next-buffer*, *previous-buffer* leafing through them all, but I need only in .py files and ignore any other.

Comment: Could you clarify your question, please?  Are you asking how to bind the keys only in `*.py` files and leave the original bindings untouched for everything else?

Comment: Have a look at [the manual node on key bindings](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html#Key-Bindings) and Mickey Petersen's [Mastering Key Bindings in Emacs](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension [Tabbar](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/tabbar.el) exactly what I looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [**Icicles**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then `C-x b` with plain `C-u` or with a zero prefix arg provides as candidates only buffers whose mode is derived from (`C-u`) or is the same as (`C-0`) the mode of the current buffer. Whether or not you bother to display the buffer names in `*Completions*`, you can cycle among them using `C-down`.

See [Icicles - Buffer-Name Input](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Buffer-Name_Input).